# maven-embedder maven-install-plugin bug? second install-file overrides first one

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin, maven-embedder

I am posting here because the maven project issue tracker ain't open without registration, and registration takes some time.

I am referring to https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html, last variant: Only specifying `-Dfile` parameter, thus using the Jar-internal POM to derive artifactId etc.

> if the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a subdirectory of the META-INF/ directory, which will be read by default.

**On the command-line I run**

```bash
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=somefile.jar -DgroupId=somegroup -DartifactId=someartefact -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=someotherfile.jar
```

This works. **Now when I use maven-embedder, it doesn't.**

What happens is:

- maven-embedder writes the first jar file correctly into the local repository.
- Then, maven-embedder writes the second jar over the previous one.

I have debugged into https://github.com/apache/maven-install-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/install/InstallFileMojo.java :

**On the second `install:install-file` goal, the `-DgroupId, -Dartifact` parameters from the first call are still somehow here and trigger the override.**

Seems to be a bug, can somebody report and fix that? Thank You.

Comment: Please explain that point: `Now when I use maven-embedder, it doesn't.` more in detail? Why do you use the maven-embber for what purpose? If you done the install-file so you are done?

Comment: @khmarbaise: what goes wrong with maven-embedder is what i wrote after "What happens is:".

Comment: I don't understand why you use it? For which purpose? That question is not answered yet? Furthermore if you use install-file it does exactly what it should. It installs the file... The other question is coming up: Why using install-file? Why is this required? Do you use a repository manager?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Well I have to admit I posted here because getting access to the maven issue tracker takes time... I'm waiting for over a week now. I hoped some maven developer would read here.
"I don't understand why you use it?" - Well I could get in detail but this gets away from my point. My point is, there is a malfunction. Did anyone recognize that yet?
The point still is, the second `install-file` call malfunctions, not using the pom of the Jarfile as intended, but somehow-cached parameters from the first call.

Comment: `I hoped some maven developer would read here` please check https://maven.apache.org/team.html If you don't go into details that will not help. That means in consequence I can not help. That would be same question I would ask if you have created an JIRA issue on the Maven project... The information is required to undestand the use case and may be able to reproduce the issue and make it possible to find a solution if it is an issue... The context information is required...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Ah you ARE part of the Maven Team? Great!
As far as I understand I shall provide context information for our use case. We have a few dozen Jar files here, some are built with maven, but all aren't published in a maven repo. One way to deal with that is installing them into the local repo, using `install:install-file`, as far as I understand. So I did that.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I could've done that using the command line, of course. But I used Java with maven-embedder - that's not forbidden, is it? And then I stumbled over the strange behaviour described above: The second call (using maven embedder) should use the groupid and artifactid from the pom inside the (maven-built ) jarfile, but doesn't, and falls back to the values of the previous call.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Any opinion on your side? Do I describe a valid maven bug? Do you need a MRE? Thank You.

Comment: First why not using a repository manager... makes it much more easier... furthermore can you create an example on Github or alike ... to what you are exactly doing?...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Well what confuses me in our discussion is: We can talk on two distinct levels. On one hand, I think there is a bug, a malfunction in maven which should be fixed, but you seem to ignore me completely on that point. I try to come up with an MRE shortly.

Comment: On the other hand, of course we can talk about in what way I can or should somehow archieve my goals. My situation is as follows: I had to convince some fellow developers to even use maven. CURRENTLY we have no own maven repository. That might come in the future. There have to be discussion to be held, there has work to be done (by a third party!) to migrate a few dozen projects to maven and push them to a custom maven repository. ...

Comment: ... My current quickstart was, simply push some (maven and non-maven jars) to the local `~/.m2` repo. But I think using this not-so-professional current practice does not make my bug filing invalid, does it?

Thirdly, I have requested access to maven jira some weeks ago, with no response as far as my Mail inbox tells me. How comes?

Comment: Create a github project which shows the problem.. or via the description which is offered here..

Comment: @khmarbaise: MRE uploaded at https://github.com/fjf2002/78041113-maven-embedder-maven-install-plugin-bug-second-install-file-overrides-first-one .